# Can I get an explanation what did I do wrong with my questions and why did I get -1s without any comment?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, asking-questions

Recently, I asked two questions:

- [Animation issues with Scrollable Tabs in Bootstrap 5 when translating lib from jQuery to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593084/bug-with-scrollable-tabs-in-bootstrap-5)
- [How to auto-adjust the height of a WebView in Xamarin.Android (or Android) based on dynamic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390589/how-to-auto-adjust-the-height-of-a-webview-in-xamarin-android-or-android-based)

In both:

- I have provided clear examples of what is happening, even a snippet in one of them.
- I have given workable code that developers can test.
- I did research and verify that none of them is a duplicate.
- I even provided my solutions as workable answers that other developers can reuse and one of them even has an NPM package published based on my solution.

Now, both have earned -1s without any comment, warning or report of my wrong doings. I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong or how I'm breaking the Stack Overflow best practices; therefore, I can avoid future misunderstandings or missteps from my side when I ask for any future question.

First update from the first answer:

I changed the title to this one:

**Animation issues with Scrollable Tabs in Bootstrap 5 when translating lib from jQuery to JS**

Hopefully, it's clear enough.

Comment: You shouldn't expect users to explain their votes. Up or down. Much less give you a "warning or report". These are anonymous by design.

Comment: I'm not an SME and did not vote, but these questions look *massive*. It's hard for people trying to help and for others checking if they have the same problem to grok such volumes of code and text.  That can seriously reduce the usefulness of questions.

Comment: Hi @yivi, I do agree. But I'd expect negative votes are related to my mistakes and something that I'm doing wrong. I'm open to feedback and improving myself. If there are new rules or changes, I'd like to understand them. I know I'm not perfect, and I'd rather update my knowledge if there is any wrongdoing from my side and collaborate with the SO effectively.

Comment: I don't know about any of that. But you mention more than once "without any comment" in this question, which makes it look like you expect users _should_ leve comments when voting. I'm just telling you it's probably best you adjust your expectations.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, I agree with you. When I come to SO to ask questions, I'd rather provide a clear description and as many details as possible. Especially, in the Xamarin case where you have a few developers in comparison to normal Android. I would rather provide something they can test and avoid expanding it.

Comment: Please note that people are not required to explain their downvotes for [numerous good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).

Comment: You're able to take criticism, but the folk who are not have conditioned the Stack Overflow voters to not comment to avoid the directed abuse they receive. This avoids conflict, but it denies those with thicker skin and a desire to learn  with a chance to learn. Yet another example of the <expletive deleted> heads ruining things for everybody.

Comment: For the second question, you don't actually say what the problem is until after you show the XML and C# code. You say that the API can return more complex HTML and then go straight into workarounds you tried. You don't actually say that the height is wrong until, *"Also, I tried to calculate the height using a JS function, and didn't work also."*

Comment: "But I'd expect negative votes are related to my mistakes and something that I'm doing wrong" - Sometimes a downvote to a question, simply means, another user did not find the question helpful.  Just like an upvote to that same question, means some other user, thought it was helpful. As for either of those users leaving comments, on the reason they issued the vote they choose to leave, I would agree the special snowflakes of the world ruined feedback to questions for everyone. The users willing to provide feedback, were abused one time to many, and now choose to avoid that feedback if they can

Comment: Hi @BSMP, would this intro be enough: I'm creating an app that is getting a dynamic HTML website from an API. My main challenge is that I need to auto-adjust the WebView height in real-time because android:layout_height="wrap_content" is not working as expected and doesn't adjust.

Hopefully, this time is clear.

Answer (score 2):

#1 is a mixed bag. The title doesn't make it clear that you're trying to convert jQuery to not jQuery, and the question includes a whole lot of content that doesn't seem relevant to the crux of your problem: performing animations. The title also doesn't mention animations at all, it just says there's a bug... is it even a bug?

#2 is outside of my expertise

Comment: Thanks, I updated the first question, would this be fine? Animation issues with Scrollable Tabs in Bootstrap 5 when translating app from jQuery to JS

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete [Some of the irrelevant information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qBOa.png). Provide a ***minimal*** representative example. Otherwise you're asking us to read and understand hundreds of lines of code that are not at all relevant to the query. You want to convert some animation stuff, that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: All the jquery in your question that you're trying to convert does is move the value of the left style from x to y over a given time period. That in and of itself isn't complicated, and when replaced with logic that replicates it it should work the same way that the jquery logic did. my concern is whether or not you tried that, if it worked, didn't work, caused a problem, etc... or if you didn't even get that far or know it was possible, etc.. If your question was simply how to animate something without jquery, that's most certainly a duplicate.

Comment: In other words, I think you fell into the trap of asking about the overall problem, rather than breaking it down into simpler easily researchable bits. Knowing that you're using bootstrap, scrollable, tabs, or whatever else, is additional information that isn't necessarily relevant to the problem unless the problem is specific to those things or can be solved by those things.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the first one :)